# Creating collection of polygons from collection of points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, clustering, polygon-creation

I have a set of points, which are spread over a wide geographical area.  I need to be able to create a set of polygons which best represent the clustered points.

In parts, some points may simply lie on their own, but in the main they are grouped, but not linked.

I have effectively created a grid of, lets say, the north western hemisphere and in each grid, have created a point with an arbitrary value.  For all values of zero, I have deleted the points, leaving the points with non zero values in them.  I now need to turn these points into polygons and am struggling a little...

Using ArcGIS and python, I thought about clustering the points, then 'convex hulling' them, but am struggling through not really knowing ArcGIS that well; how do I cluster?

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would k-means clustering suffice?, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: The same question (but without the ArcGIS emphasis) was discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6323/664 .  Also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6787/664 for a closely related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I made a recursive function which, effectively, stored cordinates of polygon/Polyline/point data by flood filling the raster based on > 0 values held there.

Answer (score 2):

There could certainly be better ways to do this, but one way I can think of is to use Thiessen Polygons in Analysis Tools>Proximity toolbox.  If I understand correctly, use your point feature with the arbitrary value as input to the Thiessen tool and you will end up with a set of polygons containing all of your data points.  Each data point will lie in the a polygon making it geographically closer to the arbitrary value that created that polygon than to any other point.

Comment: I have looked at, actually created them, but I want to have a layer of polygons and the physical separation (white space) between them.

Comment: I am not thinking I need to query a point, buffer it, and see what points it comes up with, add them to a collection, then buffer them, to see what new points they come up with, creating a record of individual polygons by point.

Comment: @Hairy I realize @badkins did not answer the question you have in your mind, but it is a reasonable response to the question you actually asked: "to create a set of polygons which best represent the clustered points."  Perhaps you could elaborate on what you mean by "best represent."

Comment: I thought I responded resonably?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool on the Geoprocessing Resource Center by Bruce Harold called the [Concave Hull Estimator](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=AA23C5C6-1422-2418-8811-1365253A756A) that may implement what you want (concave hulls):

> Derives a polygon feature class that estimates the concave hull, or
>   footprint, of an input point feature layer.

Comment: What I mean, is effectively shrink wrapping a set o fpoints into a polygon?  Does that make sense?