# How to create polygon made from outside points of points shp?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form, clip, concave-hull

I have DEM Data which is in SHP Format. After interpolating to raster, I need to clip the raster image. To do this, I need to transform the Point SHP into a Polygon SHP using only the outer-most points to create the polygon. A Convex Hull does not produce the required results as shown in the diagram - The red outline is the Convex Hull. The arrows show the areas which should also be clipped.

[image]

I Have FME and ArcGIS Advanced.

Comment: In particular the [answer by @JasonScheirer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7365/115) that recommends Bruce Harold's [Concave Hull Estimator](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=AA23C5C6-1422-2418-8811-1365253A756A) looks like it may be exactly what you are after.

Comment: There is an alternative.  By the looks of it you have a regular grid of points (barring the gaps with arrows). Convert the points to raster directly (no interpolation) so that each raster cell where there is a point has a value of 1 and all other areas are NoData (easy in GDAL and ArcGIS). Just be sure to specify the same resolution as your interpolated raster. Then simply multiply your interpolated raster by this new one.