# How to get the geometries based on column values in postgis?

Tags: postgis

I have the following table in postgis [image]

I want to group the species along with geometries based on column values of 'val' i.e

```
11,11,11,11,11,11,11-corresponding species
          6,6-corresponding species
          12,12-corresponding species
```

How to do this in postgis?

Comment: By group do you mean filter layer by species class?

Comment: no I want to filter all the species based on 'val' column value

Comment: You should be able to filter by a simple SQL select query.  What app are you wanting to view the filtered val geometries in (e.g. QGIS)?

Comment: do you also want to combine the geometries for each value of `val`? (similar to [qgis dissolve by attribute](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/73519/55203)?)