# Dissolve Field Not Showing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, dissolve

Using QGIS 3.6

Currently trying to dissolve a polygon layer by FIELD values. QGIS 3.6 and the fields won't show up. In fact I am unable to dissolve by FIELD for any layer in my entire project.

- If I select the polygons manually and dissolve it works.(as expected)
- If I select dissolve with no polygons selected it dissolves the entire layer. (as expected).

But dissolve by fields despite the FIELDS having every type (String, Real, Integer) wont work.

[Merging/Dissolving polygons by Common Attribute Field in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73519) appears to be the only mention of this issue. Solutions are to create non-float FIELDS (I've done) and Fix Geometry(done as well).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by selecting "run as batch process" from there I was able to select the fields. I don't know why this is, perhaps the shapefile is too large (3000).