# Seeking data on population per postcode district in UK

Tags: data, united-kingdom, population, postcode

I'm searching for a data set which contains the population of each postcode district (e.g SG1 or LE2) in the UK. I'm struggling to find this anywhere especially for free.

Is there anywhere I can find this data the more recent the better?

Comment: Data requests belong to OpenData.SE, sorry. Still, have you checked with official data sources? Maybe you have to create this data yourself from zip-areas and pop-density.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32321/seeking-postcode-shapefiles-for-uk for the boundaries and worldpop for population count/density: https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/country?iso3=GBR

Comment: worldpop seems to provide data at a say 100m resolution not a postcode district resolution?

Comment: National Statics (UK) has this data  https://data.gov.uk/dataset/72d8bf63-7cc2-48b6-8d97-a85d482bf29c/national-population-database (April 2020)

Answer (score 1):

A search for "postcode district population" leads me to an FOI request which points me to table KS101EW in the Nomis census data.

I'm then about four clicks from this spreadsheet:

[image]

with 2011 census population. You didn't specify a population time point. This time next year you might get 2021 census population.

This is England and Wales only, so you'll have to get S and NI separately. They might be on Nomis somewhere.

Comment: I was ideally looking for the most up to date data that I can find. 2011 should be suitable enough however.